# Can access jenkins (ip:port 22) but not ssh

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ec2

Before adding a rule, ssh was working fine. For Jenkins, I added the custom tcp security group rule (8080) so i could access it. Then jenkins was working fine. Now, ssh does not.

[Security Group rules screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bStlh.png)

Even after removing the custom tcp which should restore the security group back to its original state, it does not ssh.

It gives ssh: connect to host ---.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection timed out

**NOTE: DO GUIDE ME IF SOMETHING IS MISSING OR NEEDS MORE EXPLANATION.**